# couldn't load memtrack module (no such file or directory) android

Tags: java, android

I`ve tried all stuff i see on internet about that i cant do it work, please help me.

Here is my Andorid Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aceptaelreto"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="8.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            />
    </application>

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

LogCat Out:

[image: LogCat Output]

As you can see i have two activities, one for loggin in and one Main, 
It was working perfectly but i get a DX error for using javax.xml.bind, i fixed removimg it and using simpleframework and now i have this issue, its driving me crazy.

If someone needs more code or more info please ask, also ill let you here the [Github Repo](https://github.com/jafroch/aceptaElReto) where you can find all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i realise that couldn't load memtrack module was not the problem, it was just a warning under it that says error to parse Xml File in line 36, i check it and i had

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            />
```

What was causing some problems, finnally i remove it and nos its all ok.